# Docusign Embedded Signing(MVC website) - tags not showing up and the document is coming as free form signing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, docusignapi

I am trying to integrate my website with Docusign via embedded signing. I have been pretty successful - thanks to the documentation and pointers from SO).

My issue is that I have a website and on initial sign up I need the users to e-sign a document before they proceed to shop at my site. So I have set up a docusign embedded signing experience once they login - which will take them seamlessly(without login to docusign server etc) to Docusign - where in the document for signing shows up  - this document is coming thru fine - but the tags are not showing up and it is showing as free form signing. There are "FIELDS" to the left of my document and I need to drag and drop these on the form ( I have populated these fields with values).

The real issue is docusign lets me "FINISH" without signing since the document is showing up as free form  - Please find my code below  - I am using the DocuSign REST API to created an embedded signing for a predefined document template using the /envelopes/{envelopeID}/views/recipient call. I am using RESTSHARP to connect to docusign. Thanks much for your help!

```
    protected const string IntegratorKey = "XX";
    protected const string Environment = "https://demo.docusign.net";
    protected const string templateRole = "Applicant";
    protected const string templateId = "XX"; 
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    protected const string AccountEmail = "XX@XX.com";
    protected const string AccountPassword = "***";
    private RestSharp.RestClient client = new RestClient();
    private RestSharp.RestRequest request;
    bool docuSignCallresult = false;

    //
    // GET: /Docusign/      
    public ActionResult launchDocusign(int id)
    {
        RestSettings.Instance.IntegratorKey = IntegratorKey;
        RestSettings.Instance.DocuSignAddress = Environment;
        RestSettings.Instance.WebServiceUrl = Environment + "/restapi/v2";

        Domain.Account currentAccount = null;
        using (var accountRepo = new AccountRepository())
        {
            currentAccount = accountRepo.AccountGet(id);
        }

        string RecipientEmail = currentAccount.Email;
        string RecipientName = currentAccount.FullName;

        Account docuSignAcct = GetDocusignAcctDetails();
        Envelope docuSignEnvelope = GetDocusignEnvelopeDetails(docuSignAcct,RecipientEmail,RecipientName);
        RecipientView rv = GetRecipientView(RecipientEmail, RecipientName);                                          

        client = new RestSharp.RestClient(Environment);
        request = new RestRequest("/restapi/{apiVersion}/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/recipient");
        request.AddUrlSegment("apiVersion", "v2");
        request.AddUrlSegment("accountId", docuSignAcct.AccountId);
        request.AddUrlSegment("envelopeId", docuSignEnvelope.EnvelopeId);

        Mysite.Web.Models.DocuSignData.AuthenticationHeader header = new Mysite.Web.Models.DocuSignData.AuthenticationHeader();
        var jsonHeader = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(header);          

        request.AddHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", jsonHeader);
        request.Method = Method.POST;
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;           
        request.AddJsonBody(rv);

        var response = client.Execute(request);          
        char[] charstoTrim = { '\r', '\n', ' ', '\'' };
        var json = response.Content.Trim(charstoTrim);
        var jo = JObject.Parse(json);
        var recipientUrl = jo["url"].ToString();
        return Redirect(recipientUrl);            
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the recipient view to launch the docusign(Embedded signing experience)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="RecipientEmail"></param>
    /// <param name="RecipientName"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>

    private RecipientView GetRecipientView(string RecipientEmail, string RecipientName)
    {
        RecipientView rv = new RecipientView();
        rv.authenticationMethod = "email";
        rv.returnUrl = Request.Url.Scheme + System.Uri.SchemeDelimiter + Request.Url.Host + "/MySiteController/MySiteActionMethod";
        rv.email = RecipientEmail;
        rv.userName = RecipientName;
        rv.clientUserId = "1";

        return rv;

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create an Envelope using the template on docusign 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="acct"></param>
    /// <param name="recipientEmail"></param>
    /// <param name="recipientName"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>

    private Envelope GetDocusignEnvelopeDetails(Account acct,string recipientEmail,string recipientName)
    {
        Envelope envelope = new Envelope();
        envelope.Login = acct;
        envelope.Status = "sent";
        envelope.EmailSubject = "Testing";
        envelope.TemplateId = templateId;
        envelope.TemplateRoles = new TemplateRole[]
        {
            new TemplateRole()
            {
              email = recipientEmail,
              name = recipientName,
              roleName = templateRole,
              clientUserId = "1"
            }
        };

        try
        {
            docuSignCallresult = envelope.Create();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error("Login to docusign failed due to {0} and the exception generated is {2}", envelope.RestError.message, ex.Message);
        }

        return envelope;

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Access Docusign Account information 
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private Account GetDocusignAcctDetails()
    {
        Account docuSignAcct = new Account();
        docuSignAcct.Email = AccountEmail;
        docuSignAcct.Password = AccountPassword;

        try
        {
            docuSignCallresult = docuSignAcct.Login();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error("Login to docusign failed due to {0} and the exception generated is {2}", docuSignAcct.RestError.message, ex.Message);
        }
        return docuSignAcct;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Generally this happens because the role name in your request doesn't match the role name in the template.  The result is that your recipient isn't actually assigned any tags.  I'd start there to ensure the recipient is getting matched up properly.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff Kyllo.. I changed the RoleName to Applicant and its not in free form signing now. But earlier I was getting my name/email address etc was populated when I drag and drop the fields.. can I not have them populated but still allow user to edit if he needs to make a change? Also on the returnUrl is it possible to get the user added values back to my website? Please let me know! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jeff has mentioned in the comments this is most likely caused by you not matching your recipient correctly to a template (placeholder) role on your template. From your code it looks like you are sending the value `Applicant` as the template role name - this means that you need to have a role called `Applicant` in your Template in the Web Console.

For instance, in the below screenshot the role name is `Signer1`:

[image: Template role name field in DocuSign Web Console]

To fix either login to the Console and name the role on your template "Applicant" or whatever name it currently has copy that into the code and send that in the API request.

Comment: Thanks @Ergin.. I changed the RoleName to Applicant and its not in free form signing now. But earlier I was getting my name/email address etc was populated when I drag and drop the fields.. can I not have them populated but still allow user to edit if he needs to make a change? Also on the returnUrl is it possible to get the user added values back to my website? Please let me know! Thanks!

Comment: @Erin,@Jeff Kyllo..Just wanted to add I figured out how to pre-populate fields of the template and I have it working. Thanks to some of the docs on docusign.