# Docusign integration with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, docusignapi

Requirement:
User 1 will upload a pdf file in our ASP.NET Core Application, afterwards with help of DocuSign , User 1 will add Signer placeholder in required pages he wants and send the document to approvers for signing, once signing by approver is completed , we need to push  the final pdf file to out ASP.NET Core application. I  checked example code downloaded from developer account from DocuSign, seems the scenario which I explained is not present in the example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does exist in example code:

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/embedded-sending/

https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-csharp/blob/master/launcher-csharp/eSignature/Examples/EmbeddedSending.cs

You can download a full working app and choose this example by going to https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/

Comment: Thanks for the response @Inbar Gazit.I check the links which you sharing, Those links are to directly send the document to signer without having signer placeholder. Here signer can place the signature anywhere in the document. My requirement is to keep the signer placeholder in the required place and send the envelope for signing. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31055841/docusign-embedded-signingmvc-website-tags-not-showing-up-and-the-document-is

Comment: you can do that too, but not clear if you want the end user to put additional tabs?

Comment: We have plenty of other examples with tabs, I think you should download the quickstart and try some of the examples

Comment: I already downloaded quick-start and working with same examples. As you mentioned, requirement is to add signer tab by end user and send the document to approver(signer).

Comment: Then you need to do the first example I linked "embedded sending"

Comment: Thanks Inbar Gazit, I read the embedded sending example and it solves my problem